# "all the thorns, that is, every regret"

Tags: phrase-usage, grammaticality

Can you replace an "all" phrase with an "every" phrase and use both in the same sentence? Is it alright to say:

> She had removed ***all the thorns*** from his heart, that is, ***every regret*** of the past, and he could not forget that.

To say "all the regrets" instead of "every regret" would sound repetitive, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

- She had made him forget every failure, and all his long-simmering regrets.
- She had made him forget all his regrets, each and every disappointment that had ever tormented him.

These sentences show that the *all* and *every* (and maybe even *each*) phrases are sufficiently similar in meaning to be used as you have used them, although of course linguists would point out that they are not semantically identical.

For your sentence, I prefer

- She had removed the thorns from his heart, his every past regret, and he could not forget it.

But this is just a stylistic change. "Thorns in the heart" is not a common idiom, and it sounds a bit strange to me, though the sense is clear.

Comment: What would you put instead of "thorns" as a metaphor?

Comment: You could try *barbs*, because these are literal spikes (including on plants), but are often used to describe things which induce emotional pain.

Comment: first time I hear it, so thanks for the new word. I am not sure you can have barbs in your heart, though. Maybe "thorns" doesn't go either, but I thought of "to have a thorn in the flesh". Still looking for another word.

Comment: You could paraphrase, then: *She had healed his wounded heart, soothed his anxious soul*, ...